# Valid characters in a class name in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

What is the set of valid characters for an Objective-C class?

Of course the basic naming conventions of letters, numbers and underscore all work, but I'm looking for a special character to avoid naming conflicts.

The $ symbol seems to work, but I could not find any documentation. The [language reference](http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/b/b6/Objective-C_Programming_Language.pdf) does not mention it.

Any other? Any "official" document I can refer to?

Comment: the `$` is left for historical reason only. do not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, Objective-C compiler has been based on GNU C compiler, which [allowed dollar signs in identifiers as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs). As far as I know, this is the only exception to the rule of naming identifiers with sequences of letters, digits, and underscores that do not start in a digit.

Since Apple switched to a different toolchain for their compilers, it appears that the dollar sign is kept for backward compatibility. I would avoid using it in my new code, especially since Apple is not advertising it as a feature.

Answer (score 3):

At compile time, the set of characters is whatever the C/C++ compiler accepts as an identifier.

At runtime, anything UTF-8 goes.

Comment: So at run time you conceivably create classes and identifiers composed of strings that would fail or cause trouble in lots of other places? Imagine invalid surrogate pairs and ASCII control characters and more. Does that pose any security risk to debuggers or Xcode or even to coders or archivers?

Comment: Or not to mention the key value coding mechanism ?

Comment: So how can you change a class' name at runtime?